# Number to letters (currency format) in french

Tags: php, numberformatter

I wanted to convert Number/Float (currency amount) to letters, for example.

```
300.00 to trois cent dollars
162.00 to cent soixante-deux dollars
251.84 to deux-cents cinquante-et-un dollars et quatre-vingt-quatre cents
```

I am using PHP's `NumberFormatter` class to convert letter to numbers, it works fine when it is just number, i am using the following code.

```
$f = new NumberFormatter("fr", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$f->format(40.50);
```

which gives me following output

```
quarante virgule cinq
```

Whereas what i want is this

```
quarante dollars et cinquante cents
```

What i want is to add dollars and cents wherever necessary in the string.

Any hint on how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably have to split the string in 2 and add the dollars/cents yourself. MONEY_FORMAT can add the $ though: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Just curious, on how you would split the string ?

Comment: With the string, I meant your numeric value. So `arr=str_split('300.00','.')` for example, giving you a way to loop over this and then apply the number formatter on the separate parts.